# Can deploy adapters but not applications in mobileFirst 7 server farm

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to deploy an application from the central mobileFirst console (IBM MobileFirst 7 with Websphere Liberty) of a server farm consisting of 2 clusters. I have modified server.xml in each server in order to change the port from 9080 to 80.

I have changed the following lines:

```
!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the Worklight Administration Console. --
 <jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"*://*:*/wladmin"'/>
```

to this:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"http://MyServerEndpoint:80/wladmin"'/>
```

Though, everytime I try to depoly an application from the central worklight console (the console of the load balancer) no application is installed without an error in the worklight console while in the server that tries the deployment I see the following error:

Received status 500 for GET http://MyServerEndpoint:9080/worklig
htadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true

Why does it go for 9080 again since I have changed it? Do I have to change something else that I haven't changed?

NOTE: When I deploy an adapter everything works fine and both servers can see the new adapter.

Comment: If it goes to 9080, it means you didn't change it everywhere.

Comment: I know but where else do I have to change it? I also changed it in worklight.properties and redeployed the war files in every server. Still the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed the **value** of the jndiName from a the original string, you made it into a URL, according to this [IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jndi.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-5-2&lang=en), if you want to bind an instance of java.net.URL into the JNDI namespace, use the jndiURLEntry configuration.  For example:

```
<jndiURLEntry jndiName="urls/IBMKnowledgeCenter" value="http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/" />
```

Comment: I will try that out and I will tell you if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunantely it didn't work. I turnt 
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"http://MyServerEndpoint:80/wladmin"'/>
to
<jndiURLEntry  jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"http://MyServerEndpoint:80/wladmin"'/> 
and when I enter the central console I get Server error. Contact the server administrator. In the logs I see:
 E Received status 500 for GET http://MyServerEndpoint:9080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true

Comment: If you're only changing the port of the endpoint, try reverting to the original jndiEntry and use instead:
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"*://*:80/wladmin"'/>

Comment: This didn't work either... I am getting the error:
 failed: Connection refused while accessing MobileFirst artifact URL: http:
//myPath:9080/wladmin/otu/1.0/ffffff904468ffffffd83c1bffffffa6ffffffe635ffffffe56b1b776c00ffffffd0/runtimes/MyContextPath/downloads/applications/Temporary317
569284/android/1.0